# Bit Field struct list

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following bitfield struct:

```
struct DescriptorByte
{
    unsigned short IsImmedCalc : 1;
    unsigned short IsPrefix : 1;
    unsigned short NoMemOp : 1;
    unsigned short Size : 5;
};
```

I want to create an table for holding many DescriptorByte struct, so i created this:

```
struct OpcodeList
{
    DescriptorByte ADD_8_MO;
    DescriptorByte ADD_32_MO;
    DescriptorByte ADD_8_OM;
    DescriptorByte ADD_32_OM;
    DescriptorByte ADD_8_OI = { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 1 + 1 };
    DescriptorByte ADD_32_OI = { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 1 + 4 };
    DescriptorByte PUSH_ES = { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 1 };
};
```

So is this the same as having an struct with each member beign 1 byte long?. Also i want to be able to reference the initializator member like this:

```
DescriptorByte ADD_8_OI = { IsImmedCalc = true, Size = 1 };
```

but visual studio is not letting me. The idea behind all of this is having a table of DescriptorByte, is this the best approach? also what is the best initialization method? thanks.

Comment: `unsigned short` is at least 16 bits long. You were probably looking for `unsigned char`.

Comment: ok thanks, any other method? i mean beside it looks ugly, maybe i want to declare some values to specific members and ignore the rest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "is this the same as having a struct with each member being 1 byte long?"

   Your compiler might add padding if you do not use `#pragma pack` or something similar.

   But there isn't any padding required in this specific case, so essentially the answer is yes.

   Just change the `unsigned short` to `unsigned char` and each member will be 1 byte long.
2. Add '.' on the left side of each field:

   `DescriptorByte ADD_8_OI = { .IsImmedCalc = true, .Size = 1 };`

   Alternatively, just write the actual values in the correct order (missing ones will be set to 0):

   `DescriptorByte ADD_8_OI = { true, 1 };`

Comment: The initializer with '.' not working here it says expression expected. thanks

Comment: "designated initializers" are only in C, not in C++

Comment: Added an alternative option

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Posted this thinking it was a C# question, sorry! Leaving it here for others.

C# does not support bit-fields. However, you can still 'emulate' that behavior using a single member variable of the appropriate size along with various getter properties.

In your example, you want to use an unsigned 8-bit integer value (`byte`) and encapsulate those bitfields. Have no fear, you can still use a `struct` to do all this to make marshaling and interop easier.

So let's take your `DescriptorByte` and recreate what you are looking to do:

```
struct DescriptorByte
{
    static readonly byte IsImmedCalcFlag = 0x80;    // 1000 0000
    static readonly byte IsPrefixFlag = 0x40;       // 0100 0000
    static readonly byte NoMemOpFlag = 0x20;        // 0010 0000
    static readonly byte FlagsBitMask = 0xE0;       // 1110 0000
    static readonly byte SizeBitMask = 0x1F;        // 0001 1111

    byte field;

    public bool IsImmedCalc
    {
        get { return (field & IsImmedCalcFlag) > 0; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                field = (byte)(field | IsImmedCalcFlag);   // Set the bit
            else
                field = (byte)(field & ~IsImmedCalcFlag);  // Clear the bit
        }
    }

    public bool IsPrefix
    {
        get { return (field & IsPrefixFlag) > 0; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                field = (byte)(field | IsPrefixFlag);   // Set the bit
            else
                field = (byte)(field & ~IsPrefixFlag);  // Clear the bit
        }
    }

    public bool NoMemOp
    {
        get { return (field & NoMemOpFlag) > 0; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                field = (byte)(field | NoMemOpFlag);    // Set the bit
            else
                field = (byte)(field & ~NoMemOpFlag);   // Clear the bit
        }
    }

    public byte Size
    {
        get { return (byte)(field & SizeBitMask); }
        set { field = (byte)((field & FlagsBitMask) | (value & SizeBitMask)); }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man but this is C++ hehehe indeed i will give you rep for the C# approach

Comment: Cool, except where does the question mention C#?

Comment: Anyway it would be a pain in the ass making it on C# there are more than 300 opcodes for intel x86/x64.